# Is there a better way to get the result im after with this while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm gonna put this into a database for example:

Enchant: enchant_id 1, 1 str, 6 dex.

That's why i'm looping through it.

I get the result i want, but is there a better way of doing this?

```
<?php
$str = 1;
$dex = 1;
while ($dex <= 7) {
    echo "Str: $str";
    echo " - ";
    echo "Dex: $dex";
    echo "<br>";
    $dex++;
    if($dex == 8) {
        echo "<br>";
        $str = 2;
        $dex = 1;
        while ($dex <= 7) {
            echo "Str: $str";
            echo " - ";
            echo "Dex: $dex";
            echo "<br>";
            $dex++;
            if($dex == 8) {
                echo "<br>";
                $str = 3;
                $dex = 1;
                while ($dex <= 7) {
                    echo "Str: $str";
                    echo " - ";
                    echo "Dex: $dex";
                    echo "<br>";
                    $dex++;
                }
            }
         }
    }
}

?>
```

This outputs:

```
Str: 1 - Dex: 1
Str: 1 - Dex: 2
Str: 1 - Dex: 3
Str: 1 - Dex: 4
Str: 1 - Dex: 5
Str: 1 - Dex: 6
Str: 1 - Dex: 7

Str: 2 - Dex: 1
Str: 2 - Dex: 2
Str: 2 - Dex: 3
Str: 2 - Dex: 4
Str: 2 - Dex: 5
Str: 2 - Dex: 6
Str: 2 - Dex: 7

Str: 3 - Dex: 1
Str: 3 - Dex: 2
Str: 3 - Dex: 3
Str: 3 - Dex: 4
Str: 3 - Dex: 5
Str: 3 - Dex: 6
Str: 3 - Dex: 7
```

How can i simplify the code to get the same result?

Comment: Hello Pino.. what are you trying to achieve? :/

Comment: it consufing, why you are using while loop, and please show you data as well, is what you are doing here, can be don in simple if statement, but i may be wrong

Comment: Why do you need all of these nested loops?  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I get the result i want, but i dont know how to make a better code. It's so messy.

Comment: @David he wants to iterate `$str` from 1 to 7 while `$dex` is 1, then start again with `$dex` set to 2 and the same for 3.

Comment: @LelioFaieta i think that's not what david ask, david ask why he want to do it like this, means what is the end result he want to achieve

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 don't mind on what he wants to do then with his code. the question is _"is it possible to simplify this"_? Then what he will do with the echoed strings is something up to him, no? :)

Comment: @David I edited it and tried to explain more. I dont know any better way of doing it, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: not sure though if you want code here is the code `for($str=1; $str<=3; $str++)
{
    for($dex=1; $dex<=7; $dex++)
    {
        echo 'Str : '. $str .' - '.' Dex: '. $dex.'<br>';
    }
    
    echo '<br><br>';
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample output you show can be achieved with a simple nested `for` loop.  For example:

```
for ($str = 1; $str <= 7; $str++) {
    for ($dex = 1; $dex <= 7; $dex++) {
        echo "Str: $str - Dex: $dex<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />"; // For the extra space between sets
}
```

The key here when looking at your desired output is to recognize the patterns.  You have an incrementing value on the left (STR) and an incrementing value on the right (DEX).  That's two loops.  The pattern is such that for each single increase on the left (the outer loop) there is a full set of value on the right (the inner loop).